# get-pip.py execution unsuccessfull

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I'm learning Python and trying to install the flask web server. As per the guidelines I am trying to install `get-pip.py` but I get several errors. No solution has worked for me yet .

I downloaded `get-pip.py` to a folder.

Opened command prompt with "Run as administrator"

Navigated to the folder where the get-pip.py is downloaded (using `cd`).

I then type `get-pip.py` and press enter, but it gives some proxy errors and finally it says like "You have a lower version installed upgrade it using Python -m pip install --upgrade"

When I execute pip upgrade as instructed, it says

```
>python -m pip install --upgrade pip 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Phyton 3.4\lib\runpy.py", line 171, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "D:\Phyton 3.4\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Phyton 3.4\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

Not sure how to get this installed. I tried to execute `pip install virtualenv` again same error as above.

Running in Windows using Python 3.4

Comment: try this `easy_install -U pip`.

Comment: @shivsn : Got error      D:\Users\703157704>easy_install -U pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Phyton 3.4\lib\runpy.py", line 171, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "D:\Phyton 3.4\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Phyton 3.4\Scripts\easy_install.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>

ImportError: No module named 'setuptools.command.easy_install'

Comment: Because i have proxy enabled in our offfice laptop . Could that be an issue?

Comment: try installing `pip` from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip)